# Get innerHTML and the element itself using CSS and Prototype?

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

This is my HTML structure:

```
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">...</div>
    <div class="div3">...</div>
</div>
```

I want the complete HTML of div3, which is

```
<div class="div3">...</div>
```

and not just its content using Prototype. I know how to get the innerHTML:

```
inner = $$('.div1 .div3')[0].innerHTML;
```

That will only give me the "...". Is there a way to select the full div or dont I see the wood for the trees?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In most (modern) browsers, you can use `outerHTML` to get the entire tag as HTML. If you want just a reference to the element itself, you already have that. If you want to use the element as a template, you can use `$([id or reference]).clone(true)` to get a complete copy of it as an extended DOM object.